# Changing the tag description for game-recommendation

Tags: discussion, tags, game-recommendation

Given that game-rec questions are no longer on-topic for the site, should we change the tag description to make this clear? At the moment, its existence with a full description gives the impression that those types of question are still OK.

Answer (score 4):

The tag's excerpt and full description were edited in August when game-recs became off-topic, and currently read:

> “Shopping” questions asking for a recommendation on a game system, product, tool, or similar are off-topic at RPG.SE as of August 24th, 2015. Click “Learn more…” or “info” for details.
>
> ---
>
> Recommendation questions, also known as “shopping questions,” are off topic at Role-playing Games Stack Exchange. Although once allowed under [restrictive community-developed guidelines](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071), these guidelines were [retired August 24th, 2015](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747) when it was deemed that the guidelines did not achieve their original goals. Thus ended RPG.SE's experiment with making [“shopping” questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on-topic.

So that's done.

As for eliminating the tag itself, it's unfortunately not an option currently because it would untag a number of existing questions and make existing game-rec questions unfindable. It also accurately describes those questions, and in the event that game-rec ever returns to RPG.se, nuking the tag now would cause more harm than good to the posts it's on.

For the time being, the tag is a necessary evil, despite the guidance in the help (which I recall but am failing to find right now) that says tags can be taken as a guide to what is on-topic. On the plus side though, it acts as “bait”† to self-label questions for closing as off-topic.

<sup>† No implications of wrongdoing intended, of course.</sup>