# Are questions in the form of "is there an RPG based on X" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've been pondering this, as shopping questions tend to be thrown out across the whole of SE. Still, it'd be a useful question to ask sometimes for some people, with potentially singular answers.

Can they be asked, and should they be?

Comment: [Related] [Can we ask about the existence of a game?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/can-we-ask-about-the-existence-of-a-game)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie  I feel like there should be a way to ask such questions in a different context, like *Who owns the license to make role-playing games based on this IP?* but I can imagine such questions becoming stealth game rec questions, too.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Context can make all the difference, yeah. If someone's real problem isn't just that they want help finding a game to play, it should work here.

Answer (score 10):

No, as these are a form of game recommendation question and these are generally not accepted on this site. There is a long, complex and contentious history behind the eventual decision to disallow this type of question, and there is still some ill-feeling about the way it was handled. However, the decision to ban them still stands.

If you're interested, do a search for the [game-recommendation] tag on meta to get the whole story.

Answer (score -5):

Yes. They are distinct from shopping questions, so long as X is specific enough (e.g. x = "Star Trek" is fine, x = "comics" is not).

If it helps to think of it differently, "how many RPGs have been based on X?" asks the same question in a different way, and is much more clearly not a shopping question.