# Is there a chat room to ask off topic questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a recommendation type question which I know are strictly off topic due to the nature of the question. I know in other stack exchanges there is a chat room where such questions can be asked openly. Does this stack exchange have a chat room or another place where I can ask these types of questions?

Related: [I want to ask for recommendations, but that's off topic. Is there any way to ask my question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/i-want-to-ask-for-recommendations-but-thats-off-topic-is-there-any-way-to-ask)

Comment: Notably, RPG General Chat is on the list in that related meta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can already ask whatever you like in [RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), and people discuss game recommendations there sometimes, so that is the chat for this.