# Are "bonus question" allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, multiple-questions-per-post

Recently I asked a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123953/which-system-mechanics-maximize-on-character-time?noredirect=1#comment306061_123953) that was put on hold for being a "Shopping" question.

I believe that is solved, asking not for a specific game but which ruleset allows what I was looking for.

Still, though, I think it is interesting to see if there exists any actual game with such ruleset implemented.

At the end of the question I included the following wording:

> Bonus (off-topic) question: Is there any actual game that follow those
>   mechanics? While this will not be valued for chosing best answer, I'd
>   appreciate any answer to this question either on the answer or
>   comments.

I'd been pointed on the comments that it's a bad practice, being it an *entirely unrelated and non-essential extra question*. I'd like to understand if it's the case and whether or not it's bad practice.

As I see it (and the reason why I kept the bonus question):

- There are many published rpg-systems.
- Given a specific rule-set, it's very probable that a game following it had been published.
- Giving an example of a rule-set being applied helps understand it and empirically proves (or disproves) that such rule-set achieves the desired dynamics.

Comment: Can this question—or the original—make clear the difference between a *game* and a *ruleset*? Further, can either question make clear how it *is* a shopping question to ask for a *list of games* yet *not* a shopping question to ask for a *list of rulesets*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As can be seen by even this meta question, mixing up multiple questions in one creates a mess.

Is asking about existence of a game on topic?  Usually no, see [Can we ask about the existence of a game?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/can-we-ask-about-the-existence-of-a-game)

Can you ask multiple questions in one question?  Usually no, see [1 post - 1 question , is it a rule or a guideline or what?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what) and [What do I do with a question that contains multiple questions in its body and/or title?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/what-do-i-do-with-a-question-that-contains-multiple-questions-in-its-body-and-or)

Is a shopping question not a shopping question because you are asking for a rule set not a game?  No, see [How can I ask for recommendations without getting my question closed as 'Shopping'](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/how-can-i-ask-for-recommendations-without-getting-my-question-closed-as-shoppin/7835#7835) and [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited).

So what can you do?  First, ask about your problem not a thing - see [I want to ask for recommendations, but that's off topic. Is there any way to ask my question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/i-want-to-ask-for-recommendations-but-thats-off-topic-is-there-any-way-to-ask) -and ask one question per question.

Answer (score 3):

As it is at the moment of this writing, it can't be opened twofold:

### The Question-list-argument

Lists of questions that are not tightly compacted, rhetorical or serve to show where confusion lies ("Did I apply this rule correctly? Did I overlook a special rule?"), any question that contains questions outside of this manner that ask for an answer, is to be closed as a List-question. [1 post - 1 question , is it a rule or a guideline or what?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what) [RULE]

### Forbidden Fruit and you

First of all, we all agree that [it is not allowed to ask for game recommendations under the current rules](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited) and call it a [fruit of a poisonous tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_of_the_poisonous_tree).

Ok, let's abstract this a little and make each reopening akin to a legal case that was based on some sort of evidence that was obtained in some illegal manner and shot down for that. The case can't continiue the trial and has to be dismissed if no new evidence comes up that is equally convincing and much more: **the item** (evidence) **may not even be mentioned** in trial, nothing may base on it.

Using this as my (personal, non-moderator) guideline, I advocate, that even the **mentioning** of asking for a game makes the whole question a game recommendation question, and thus holdable till that part is completely omitted.