# Our "On Topic" page still implies game-recs are on topic

Tags: support, on-topic

["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) still says:

> Do some research before asking for games that have/do X so that you're asking an answerable question - also review the [site guidance on asking game recommendation questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic).

That "site guidance" link leads to an out-of-date ruling on game recommendations. It's closed with a link forward to our current policy, and *technically* "review the site guidance" isn't saying game-rec is allowable, but it's a very misleading run-around:

- Do research before asking game-rec questions, and...
- ...read this link for guidance on asking game-rec questions:
- Sorry, that's an old link. Here's the new one:
- Actually, don't ask game rec questions at all.

Can we have our on-topic page actually say game-recs aren't on topic, and link directly to the up-to-date meta discussion? It probably won't alert people who also miss the big "OFF TOPIC--DO NOT ASK" on the tag, but it can't hurt and will provide a consistent, less frustrating site experience for those beautiful unicorns who *do* read the Help pages.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the catch! It's been updated now. The current wording of that bullet is

> - If you're looking for a game mechanic or technique that does thing *X*, ask for how to do *X*, not for "games that have *X*". Asking for one or a list of games is a game recommendation question, [which are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited).

I've also update the section “This is *not* the right site for questions about” to add a third bullet:

> - Computer RPGs or MMOs - for those, see [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
> - Card games, TCGs, miniatures games, or board games - for those, see [boardgames.stackexchange.com](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com)
> - Recommendations for RPGs to play - for those, use [an RPG discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: Hooray! Phrasing suggestion: "Asking for a game, or a list of games, is a game rec..." etc.

Comment: @BESW Good idea. Done!

Comment: Game identification questions are still on-topic though, right?  From my reading of the old description, that on-topic bullet point would have covered them then, but now it seems to say those types of Qs are off-topic.

Comment: @LegendaryDude That'd be a good separate meta question, I think.