# Is this a shopping question?

Tags: discussion

I really want to find a nice, high-quality map of Faerun for D&D. I've found plenty of copies, snips and scaled-down versions but they're all horribly blurry up close and make reading any of the names an entertaining but useless guessing game.

My question is whether a high-quality, full-size map is available for download or purchase online somewhere (buying a physical copy is an unideal but legitimate option), but I think that counts as a shopping question, right?

Comment: Already asked—and closed—[here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112127/8610), yet your proposed question would've potentially included stricter criteria and more information.

Comment: @HeyICanChan mmm, yeah the result for that question was actually too broad - I specifically want Faerun with major cities/towns/landmarks labeled. But I suppose if that one got closed mine would be too?

Comment: Yep, it probably would. (I only remembered that other question because *I wanted to see that map, too.* Not that I have any leads—I was just curious.)

Answer (score 7):

## It's a [shopping question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7413/8610)

Such a question would likely be closed as an inexact duplicate of this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112127/8610). While the new question would have slightly different guidelines and requirements, those who respond can't currently and legally produce (or *re*produce) what the question asks for, but only explain *where* what's asked for can be acquired. This makes such questions out of scope for the site.

I suggest asking for information in chat or on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) where discussions can be held instead.

Comment: Entertaining the concept for a moment that a shopping question would be on topic (it isn't), we *could* show them a scaled-down illegible version of the map as a preview of what they'd get for purchasing something, much like Wikipedia hosts low-res imagery under fair use -- but we could never just give them a high-resolution version without it being effectively a request to assist in piracy, which we'd be obliged to not be party to, unless that high-resolution version was already free & something we could redistribute.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yeah, sure. (The essential problem is that, fundamentally, I don't think this is actually a question but a request: *Provide me a map to Toril using these specifications* is what the site really, really wants to do with such semiquestions… *and it just can't.* The only way I could imagine a question similar to this being on topic would be along the lines of *Is this specific map of Toril accurate?* then an expert could evaluate *that map* and, during that evaluation, for comparison perhaps provide links to maps that are more or less accurate.)