# Revising my question to not get opinion-based answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [Is there a particular version of D&D that is easier to convert to 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112187/is-there-a-particular-version-of-dd-that-is-easier-to-convert-to-5e) on the main site, seeking advice on converting prior editions to D&D 5e. It has been put on hold as too broad and primarily opinion-based. How can I revise it to make it work with their format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Cut out the bit looking for recommendations of specific modules. It's too broad, among a whole host of other problems that recommendations generally cause. (See [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited) if you want to read more, start following links there if you really want to fall down a hole.)
2. Once you've done that it's starting to look more approachable. There are only ten or so (depending on how you count) different editions of D&D, after all. And I know experienced site members have done conversions, and have experience with lots of D&D. And are willing (and happy) to write up high-quality answers that look at lots of editions' material. (I'm thinking of [How do interpretations of Hit Points vary among D&D editions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108454/23970) which was recently referenced, or [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212/23970) for example.)

   I do think it perhaps necessary to lay out your priorities a bit. Specifically:

   - you say you have AD&D experience--any other editions? A little bit about how much you know them could help
   - what your desired playstyle focuses on--combat, role-play, exploration, combat-as-war vs. combat-as-sport, many-year campaigns, one-shots, monty-haul vs. edge-of-survival, and all the things I haven't thought of
   - then share any experience you do have with converting: which bits did you find enjoyable, which a slog, what're problems that cropped up in your 5e that you didn't foresee, &c.

Comment: One of the issues I saw once we reach step 2 was "which ones are [easy/easier] to convert?" is a completely subjective, effectively wholly undefined criteria. What is "easy"?

Comment: I agree in part, which is why some info about OP's situation could help. If "I want to make excellently-balanced combat-as-sport encounters that easily balance the contributions of casters and martials," I think we all know there's one edition that should be looked at. If "subtracting from 20 is a mental block for me," we know one to rule out =) Maybe I should describe point 2 as "necessary" rather than a "help"?

Comment: After reading your answer, "What are the big differences between the D&D editions?",  and reviewing the comments  I think the major difficulty is I have no clear goal. When I have a specific item to translate I can ask targeted questions.