# What should our pro-forma system-recommendation comment be?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendation

Given that we're gearing up for a default comment, let's get some community input on what the *best* comment for describing our sys-req questions should be.

I'll post some of the ones we've used as answers. Upvote *and edit* the best.

Comment: 2 by mxy, 2 by me should provide enough of a sample basis for editing and upvoting.

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible. (Auto Insert Test)

Comment: @C.Ross that looks good.

Answer (score 12):

> As this is a [system-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-recommendation) question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

### Formatted for [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

```
###System Recommendation 
As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.
```

Comment: Do we want to link meta as well?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Where on meta, the question you reference?

Comment: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760

Comment: Hmmm, autoreviewcomments is nifty, but it doesn't have the same weight as a post notice.

Answer (score 4):

Please answer this question following the site guidance on game-rec questions - "you could do this, I suppose" is wrong, "I have done this and here's what I did" is right. meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/… Expect to be downvoted if your answer does not include personal experience or a relevant reference.

Answer (score 2):

Tag Wiki:

System recommendation questions must be tightly scoped to be allowed on RPG.SE; see our System Recommendation Q&A Guidance for more. Closely define what you need and then answers must follow ["Good Subjective, Bad Subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) criteria and only recommend what they have experience in and not just toss out Googled lists.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this question should conform to our game recommendation question guidelines - you should be posting games you have personally used or seen used for the purpose and providing detail on the results. meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/… - simply listing games you have heard of/pulled off the net is a downvotable answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just a note folks, remember that our sys-rec questions require a [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) basis. You must have played the system within the context of the requirements to recommend it. Please consider *all* the requirements before nominating your favorite system.