# Are the questions about the game choice for given situation on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are the questions about choosing the game system for given social situation on-topic here?

As example, I would like to ask, which game is good for the train travel in the group 4 to 8 people, which travel duration 3 to 8 hours? The game should be possible to finish in a few hours and should not require much place. But... is such question on-topic on this SE, or rather is adequate for other SE?

Comment: Is this for RPG or board games? It sounds like a board game would suit you better.

Comment: It could, but it requires a lot of place. But I've considered also playing a RPG session in train - but have no idea, which system would enable so fast game.

Comment: I can think of at least one game that's designed for just that circumstance: Zak Snyder's STACK. http://dndwithpornstars.blogspot.com/2012/04/fast-light-cheap-instant-rpg-for-long.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So long as you abide by our [System Recommendation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic) guidelines, you'll be fine. Just make sure that there's a way to assess which game is best. Asking "What game doesn't need much space" will get you the usual suspects of FATE, various flavours of basic D&D, and the small games of choice (like minimus). Make sure that we can narrow down the list.

Answer (score 2):

We already have one question that's very much that sort of question: [Which role-playing systems might be best suited for use over a road-trip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/which-role-playing-systems-might-be-best-suited-for-use-over-a-road-trip)

It's possible to see this sort of question as being "too localized" and therefore outside the scope of the site's purpose. On the other hand, it is very much solving a real problem, and it can be useful to other people. We also have lots of recommendation questions for things like certain age groups or time frames, and no-one has raised any concerns about those being too specific. Solving a real problem seems to trump localization unless it's really only ever going to help *one* person.