# Are questions about play-by-mail/email games acceptable?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is it acceptable for me to ask questions about play-by-mail/email games, and for suggestions of PBM games to try?

Comment: This might help explain things, too: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about play-by-mail/e-mail RPGs are considered on-topic for RPG Stack Exchange.

There is a tag for them: [play-by-post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play-by-post).

System recommendation questions are on-topic as well, but have [their own specialized guidelines](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic).

Comment: "System recommendation questions are on-topic" not anymore :(