# Query over mod closing of question of 'poor reader' question

Tags: discussion, questions, game-recommendation, moderation

I am confused as to why this question has been closed...

[Are there any RPGs that a first grade reader can read and learn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31206/rpg-for-a-very-poor-reader)

...with comments added by mods for answers to show how they have experienced running the games they have given for young children. The reason for my confusion is that the question isn't asking anything about the playing of games, only the reading level of the literature that makes up the rules. The question even explicitly states that they are happy for violence to be present in whatever settings are suggested.

Given this is the case, why are mods still insisting that answers have experience of having run the game with young players when this isn't specified as a criterion by the question?

EDIT: It almost feels like the 'you must have experience of playing the game you recommend' criterion is being applied to all game-rec questions when actually there are some where it shouldn't as it is not relevant.

Comment: Seems like the kind of experience needed here is having read the book, or even better, knowing (or being) some poor reader that have understood the game.

Comment: [This link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) is required reading to understand our game-rec policy. Effectively, yeah, an answer must be based on experience solving the problem in the question, either your own or someone else's experience.

Answer (score 8):

This question, specifically, was closed to allow answerers a day to clean up their answers to Back It Up! before they're deleted. I've also commented on every. bloody. offending. answer, such that they know they're in danger of deletion.

The requirement is, in-fact, being applied to all questions in [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) because of [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic). It is the moderation policy of the site that, as shopping questions tend to be horrible list-answers that attract everyone's favourite system, requiring people to Back It Up! allows us to winnow out, *extremely* aggressively, answers that are unfounded in fact.

If you feel this is a problem, I encourage the community to pose the banning of shopping questions. We will, in no circumstances, relax this requirement, but we are happy to listen to the community in dissallowing these questions entirely.

Comment: +1, the current answers are mostly junk and not bothering to adhere to Back It Up! is a strong underlying reason why. If you have no first hand knowledge of a kid playing the game, then you're talking out your ass, period end of story.

Comment: My answer was critized not because I didn't play with a kid (which I did), but because the kid didn't prepare the game on its own, with only the text itself. Instead, I translated it for him using the materials when we played (since English is a third language for him). Brian seemed to think that's not enough. Sure, you can think it's a junk answer, but the Monster Slayers game is still the best simplified rpg for kids. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

The second paragraph is:

> I need a game that a young boy can read on his own and learn to play. I'll help him, but only after he reads it and gives a good-faith effort to come to our session having an idea what to do.

The question's title only mentions reading ability, but the entirety of the question's body is about a *kid* - one who's a couple of grades behind in his reading ability. Dealing with kids is very much a criterion of the question, so answers have to deal with that.

To make that plain, let's suppose there's a theoretical RPG that only really makes sense to people who grew up in the 70s, even if it's good for people in the 70s who read at a level behind their peers. That's not really going to be a satisfactory answer to this question.