# Permanent banner for game-recommendation tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, game-recommendation

On every question (correctly) tagged with [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation), somebody comes along and leaves a comment reminding answer's how to address the question properly. To make this more permanent than the ephemeral comments, RPG.SE mods should request a permanent banner be set up.

For example, Physics.SE uses these on book-recommendation questions, see [Shog's answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5243/6634).

**EDIT**

So this edit is mostly just to bump the activity to the front page. It would appear that the answer by SevenSidedDie is a minor tweak on the wording in my answer and the difference in votes between the two could just be attributed to age (mine came first).

Therefore -- in order to resolve this question and move on, I'll give it another day or so for comments for/against and I will accept SevenSidedDie's answer. Any objections or further discussion, leave a comment or pick it up in chat and let's finish this off!

Comment: Interesting, we asked in the past and never got any positive feedback, thanks for linking that in Physics.

Comment: @C.Ross Nobody knew it was possible over there, it was just dropped on us unexpectedly (and it's awesome)! Maybe with a precedent example you guys can get more traction if you ask again.

Comment: I think your post counts as asking.

Comment: I'm amazed that this feature has been around since 2011 and it's so little known! Yes, that is exactly what we need for game-rec.

Comment: Is this something devs must do, or is it a hidden option that site mods can access? I couldn't tell from Shog's answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe the devs have to do it. We were told to ping them if we wanted more/changes/etc..

Comment: We can do this for you guys if you guys come up with some verbiage for us to use (let's poke... coin flip... @CRoss as an additional name here).

Comment: @C.Ross Can we make this Featured until we come up with a good wording? It would be good to get the attention of those who use this tag.

Comment: *"So this edit is mostly just to bump the activity to the front page."* - It was already there, and it's featured, so you didn't have to worry about the bumping part. But, message appreciated!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I knew that but I guess what I meant to say is "make it look active so people look at it again" rather than let it be forgotten for awhile...

Comment: @C.Ross As tpg2114 commented on SSD's answer, we seem to have agreed on this answer and there have been no strong objections. Could you ping the dev group and get this set up?

Comment: @tpg2114 Thank you for bringing this feature to our awareness and taking the initiative in getting it added. I really appreciate it, and I'm sure others here do too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done, tweaked as follows:

> As this is a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question, please adhere to the [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/about), the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [our rules for game recommendations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071). **All responses must cite actual experience or reference others' experiences!**

Comment: Thanks! When will this start to show up on game-rec questions? Currently I don't see it, e.g. on [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34485/1204).

Comment: Whenever the mods here start using it - go ahead and flag questions that you think badly need it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this can be manually enabled for each particular question. Will the mods be able to make this always active for every question under the game-rec tag? Currently every game-rec question gets the standard guidance comment, since we're prone to getting a certain kind of problematic answer in those questions.

Comment: @Shog9 Something's off about the last X in experiences. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35654/is-there-a-sea-creatures-rpg-system-or-would-i-need-to-create-one

Comment: That seems to be what our X looks like when it's bolded and at that _precise_ size. If I zoom in or out one step with ctrl and +/-, it gets back in line with the other letters. Maybe our notices should be just slightly bigger?

Comment: Whut. That's just strange.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused how this works - we usually just cut and paste the notice to game-recs, I thought this would be automatic - how is this helping?

Comment: I see, arguably it's more prominent... But requires us, as opposed to anyone else adding the blurb.

Comment: Read the thread tpg linked to at the start of this, @mxyzplk - the point is that it keeps meta information out of the actual post content. If you want to slap this on all tagged questions, we can probably tear through those pretty quickly - but doing this automatically isn't usually desirable, since ideally there's some experienced human oversight involved in determining whether it's appropriate.

Comment: @Shog9 in 99% of cases it is desirable, so we'd rather use our human oversight to remove it in the 1%.

Comment: Ok - all currently-tagged questions that aren't closed, deleted or locked now have the notice, @mxyzplk. Remove where needed, and add as new ones appear.

Answer (score 14):

> As this is a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question, please adhere to both the [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760). In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience or cited references to others' experiences.

This is mostly the same text [as in tpg2114's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3329/321) and that we've been using in comments to game-rec questions, but with "and" in the last sentence changed for "or" and the following words adjusted to fit that change.

The change is to more accurately reflect the GSBS guidelines and its Back It Up! principle, which requires answers to be based on experience: your own *or* using references to someone else's experience. Otherwise, our banner will be more restrictive than the actual guideline we are using to explain it.

Comment: @C.Ross Since there were no objections, can you guys ping the dev group and get this set up?

Comment: @tpg2114 C.Ross never heard that ping. You can only ping the post author, other commenters on the same post, editors of the post, or those who are involved in closing or reopening a question if you're commenting on the question itself (I think). I'll leave a comment on the main question.

Answer (score 9):

Note: I don't really have any strong opinions on the wording since I don't actually do anything other than lurk around reading questions. If a mod comes along and leaves a comment on this answer, I'll "accept" it and ping Grace Note to use the wording here. Competing wordings (unless super minor edits to this one) should probably be a separate answer so the voting can sort out what the community wants.

So I guess since nobody has come up with the wording yet, I'll just propose that it be exactly what gets put in the comments now:

**Banner Wording**:

> As this is a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question, please adhere to both the [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760). In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: This is pretty much our staple wording at the moment, so this is good enough for me. Those who frequent game-rec might want to provide some input here though!

Comment: I've found that banner misleading. The Good Subjective, Bad Subjective page has a dead link to the Back It Up! Principle, preventing further sourcing. Further, the Back It Up! Principle as presented on that page mandates *either* actual experience *or* references, not both, like the banner does without justification. Just sayin'.

Comment: @HeyICanChan If you have an alternative proposal, write it up! This is here just to get the ball rolling and because it's the default comment used currently.

Comment: I think that's an invalid critique - that link is dead, sure, but they then go on to explain the principle at length in the post itself. We're not interested in traceability to origin, that's the guidance right there in that blog post.  I endorse this wording.

Comment: I also endorse this wording.

Comment: I don’t object to this wording but am holding off on my vote to see if @HeyICanChan can come up with a better one.

Comment: I also have a problem with the "and" that @HeyICanChan points out, where GSBS mandates an "or" at most. It has caused problems here in the past, which have been fixed by extensive commenting, but that's something we should fix at the source in this wording. I like this wording otherwise; we just need to get rid of that misleading "and".

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, put up your own answer with your optimal wording.

Comment: I don't think the and is wrong in this case - the wording is different than the GS/BS "experience or a reference"; if something's based on experience then we want examples right?

Comment: Since no-one advocating "or" over "and" is going ahead and doing it, I figured I might as well post that variant:

"As this is a game-recommendation question, please adhere to both the FAQ and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in Good Subjective, Bad Subjective and on our Meta. In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience or contain references, and should include relevant examples."

Comment: @GMJoe, I don't see your answer. Putting it in a comment doesn't actually allow voting :)

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Own answer up put!

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton You can upvote comments, even if they won't be ranked as a result. More relevantly, I interpreted this question as asking whether such a banner would be appropriate, not what the wording of such a banner should be. As such, a comment on this answer seemed more appropriate. It seems public opinion is against me, though, so I've upvoted SevenSidedDie's answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate pitch.

**Banner Wording:**

> A game recommendation question must adhere to those guidelines in the FAQ and follow the rules for subjective questions as described in Good Subjective, Bad Subjective and on the Meta. An answer to a game recommendation question must be based on personal experience playing the recommended game and, when possible, contain references to and examples from the recommended game.

That is, if the idea is to be clear that answers must share personal experiences. If I'm mistaken, let me know, but this is the sense I've gotten based on questions like [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30783/games-where-some-characters-can-play-as-weapons) wherein a moderator says, "Answers that do not present personal experience here will be deleted," despite the current banner's *should* wording and the *references **or** experiences* of the Back It Up! Principle.

I've tweaked the wording a *tiny* bit, but the issue remains. If personal experience playing the game is mandatory for a game recommendation, that *really does* need to be clear in the banner.

Comment: Language like *"personal experience participating in the recommended game"* doesn't jive with the game rec tag, since it is [also for recommendations for stuff *for* games](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3251/). A significant portion of game rec answers aren't recommending a game at all!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs It does, however, jibe with the game rec questions for actual games I've read that include moderator warnings that if personal experience *isn't* involved the answer'll be deleted without warning; I figured being up front about that was important. Suggest an edit?

Comment: I don't have a particular suggestion for this wording taking the game-rec tag as is, so this has prompted me to try to [reconcile the issue a different way](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3335/1204).

Comment: well, participating in that game/using that product... Seems like a fine hair to split.