# How should we deal with game-recs now that we have a notice?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendation

We now have [this notice](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3432/1204) that can get added to our [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) questions. An example is [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25329/1204).

> As this is a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question, please adhere to the [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/about), the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [our rules for game recommendations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071). **All responses must cite actual experience or reference others' experiences!**

It would seem this has to be manually switched on by a moderator for each question, so our new game-rec questions could sometimes go a few hours before they get the notice added.

Dear diamond mods: what course of action would you like us to take on new game-rec questions, if we spot them before you've added a notice?

- Leave the above message on a comment, and let you delete it and replace it with the actual notice when you see the new question?
- Do nothing, and let you just add the notice later?
- Something else?

---

Since we should be leaving this notice as a comment, here it is in easily copyable code form:

```
As this is a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question, please adhere to the [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/about), the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [our rules for game recommendations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071). **All responses must cite actual experience or reference others' experiences!**
```

Comment: Is there any reason its not automatically being added? Shouldn't it, optimally, appear automatically on questions that have been tagged as game-req?

Comment: 'cuz historically, notices are only applied to specific questions, so I guess that feature was simply never added

Comment: I smell a new feature request, haha.

Comment: @Jason_c_o [Allow the community to attach the game-rec post notice or tie it directly to the tag](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3442)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the usual notice text as a comment.  I at least was under the impression that the post notice would auto-add for that tag, but since it doesn't, I would rather the community be able to post the message in a comment than require a diamond mod to do it and have it be arguably more prominent.

We'll use the post notice if we happen across one, but otherwise do feel free to simply paste the usual text into a comment.

Comment: I was under the same impression.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a case where flagging would be silly. It makes for an odd workflow for mods and puts a permanent black mark on the record of the user who asked a question that is quite likely in bounds for this site.

I think the best bet is perhaps to add the post notice as a proforma comment, and then move on. The mods can stop in and add the post notice as they arise. This gets the right information across in a way that a mod can remove with a single click when they add the post notice.

However, the *best* thing we can do is lobby for users to be allowed to add post notices as a part of the reputation based privilege system. Better (non-mod dependent) tools for post notices is something the Skeptics and Christianity communities have asked for and should be something that we begin pushing for as well.

There are a few of these proposals on MSO and a couple of per-site metas when I find them I'll post them here.

- https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/add-a-review-queue-for-posts-with-a-citation-needed-notice
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189528/170797

I've added a feature request to our meta to get the ball rolling from our point of view. You can find it [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3442/1084)

Comment: Just a note I wasn't suggesting we flag anything! But yes, I think this is a good idea - including if at the very least >20k users could add post notices too!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs aye, I just wanted to confirm that it's a bad option here. That's our official channel to get a mod's attention, and it's the only tool we have that actually fulfills what we need here. It's just a bad one to use in this case :(

Comment: Flagging "needs mod attention" doesn't involve any kind of black mark, does it?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it creates a permanent record on the user's profile, yes. It's not usually a big deal, but it's something that should be avoided for something like that.