# Allow the community to attach the game-rec post notice or tie it directly to the tag

Tags: feature-request, game-recommendation, post-notice

So we have a post notice now for game-rec questions. That's great, there's just one problem.

Only 3 people on this site are capable of applying it.

This request is for one of two things, either:

- Apply the tag automatically when [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) is applied. Since this is a notice that should appear on *all questions with this tag* it would be appropriate to add it to all of them automatically. There are some legitimate concerns on the code base side that Grace Note alludes to [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14497344#14497344). I don't know the codebase, and I don't know how much SE would be willing to change the model here just for us.

OR

- Allow normal users to apply (and potentially review via the queues) applications of post notices, or a subset of them. Honestly, the post notices are as follows

  - Citation Needed
  - Insufficient Explanation
  - Current Event
  - Custom Post notice per-site

  These all (with the possible exception of Insufficient Explanation), seem like that can be applied by high users with a minimal amount of review. I'm of the mind that this should be a rep based privilege akin to protecting questions. Let is happen right away, let high (~10-20k) rep users add it and then queue them up to be reviewed a few days later to see if the post has been edited that the post notice is no longer appropriate.

Over the last 3 months, we've averaged about 2 of these a week. That's obviously not too much, but if the post notice is going to be a useful feature it has to be something that more than 3 of us can apply.